# How can I highlight a searched for word in data I render out?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a search box that let's a user search for a word.  When they search for a word I suggest a few links and when they click on a link I render out the data associated with that link below it.

Would it be possible to highlight the searched for word in the data I render out?  I'm using ReactJS and want to scan the string I'm about to render out ( obj.content ) and highlight the word that was searched for in blue.

I imaged I would have to add a check statement or some sort of CSS to my render functions.  The searched for word is in obj.content and can appear multiple times.

If I could add an html span tag to the word I think it would work.

EDIT:  Maybe where I render out obj.content I add a check to the string if the searched for string appears, get the length of the string - back up that many spaces add a CSS span tag - move forward that many spaces add a CSS span tag and continue?

```
const getRawHTML = html => ({
    __html: html
 }):

const renderOutData = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
   return this.state.searchedWord === obj.name;   
  }).map((obj, idx) => {
      return (
       <div key={idx}>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getRawHTML(obj.content)}></div>
       </div>
     );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are your friend.

Use `String.replace` with a dynamic regex to wrap the target word in an `em` or something.

```
obj.content.replace(new RegExp('(' + string ')', 'ig'), '<em>$1</em>')
```

There are a few questions you would do well to consider very carefully:

- should it be case-sensitive?
- should it apply to whole worlds only? (e.g. what about "test" within "testing")

**You also need to work hard to protect against injection attacks.**

You're already using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. By hooking the search box up to it, you're rolling out the red carpet to hackers. There are steps you can take to sanitize user input and protect yourself. **You have been warned.**

Comment: should not be case sensitive and I've written this in Electron to make it a Desktop web application not connected to the internet  - so I'm not too worried about attacks.  I'll see if I can get this to work - thanks for the reply

Comment: So something like this?  :   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getRawHTML(obj.content,replace(new RegExp('(' + this.state.searchedWord ')', 'ig'), '<em>$1</em>))}</div>

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I don't think I'd do it all inline like that, but you seem to have the gist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/autosuggest-highlight

It helps you decorate the text you are searching for.

You can see a demo here https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete.

A simple example could be:

```
const text = 'React rules!'
const searchedWord = 'Re'

const matches = match(text, searchedWord)
const parts = parse(text, matches)

const highlightSearch = parts.map((part, index) => {
  return part.highlight ? (
    <span key={index} style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>
      {part.text}
    </span>
  ) : (
    <strong key={index}>
      {part.text}
    </strong>
  )
})
```

the rendered result will be: **Re**act rules!